# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest returns "The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: powershell, download, invoke, webrequest

The script I'm writing is about downloading list of report files filtered by different parameters.
Here is my download function:

```
Function DownloadReportFiles
{    
    [OutputType([String])]

    Param
    (
        [Object]$LoginSession,
        [Object]$PostParams,
        [String]$ReportOutputResult,
        [String]$ReportSource
    );

    ForEach($Param in $PostParams)
    {

        Try
        {          
            $ReportRequestInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ReportSource -Method POST  -OutFile $ReportOutputResult -Body $Param -WebSession $LoginSession -PassThru -TimeoutSec 120;
            return $ReportRequestInfo 
        }
        Catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message;
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

$PostParam is an object with dictionary elements.

The problem is that If one report fail to download, all others fail too right away (without waiting the timeout and i have timeout set to 2 min). First it throws "Connection timeout" and then for the other files "The remote name could not be resolved". Why doesn't it wait for the timeout? I want the script to just skip that one file and continue trying to request the other files.

How can I achieve that?

I checked all the variables that I'm passing and they are OK on each loop iteration. The session is there, the url is correct and the parameters too. 
I don't know what I do wrong.

**Update:**
This is how a request with parameters looks like:

"https://example.com/DownloadingService.asp?Statement=REPORTV2&Format=PDF&ReportID=RankingReport&PCmsModel=-1029&PCmsLocationID=101&PCmsCampaigns=Wave3"

Comment: You need to provide an example of the parameters that you're passing that are not working. Impossible to tell what is wrong from just looking at the function

Comment: for me this works fine, if i supply 2 regular site and 1 bogus site

Comment: Is it possible to be a problem from my machine? Because the exception message is weird.

Comment: @arco444 I added an example of the request in the question.